# Open source Organizational Chart Creation

Tags: php, ajax, open-source, organizational-chart

I was wondering what free or open source options there are out there for creating organizational charts?

Comment: What does AJAX have to do with this? Shouldn't it be PHP/Javascript, if anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very good solution made by Google : http://code.google.com/intl/el-GR/apis/chart/

Comment: You are alway welcome ! :)

Please if you feel good with that answer rate up :)

Answer (score 0):

There is also [pChart](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/).